# Text search in Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I have some mongoose schema:

```
const Article = new Schema({
    name:                            { type: String,     required: true },
    message:                         { type: String,     default: "" },
    searchField:                     { type: String,     default: ""  },
    ...
});
```

searchField is a combination of name and message fields.

And index:

```
Article.index({searchField: 'text'});
```

Then when I need search in list of Articles:

```
query.$text = { $search: data.search }.
```

And it works, but with some problems.

The first one - it can't find Article when data.search.length <= 3. For example, name = 'bag' and data.search = 'bag', it doesn't work (ok if language is english).

And the second one - if name = 'subtitles' and data.search = 'sub', there is no result.

What is wrong?

MongoDB shell version: 3.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search with a regex. Change your query to this:

```
Article.find({searchField: /sub/i});
```

The double `/` allows you to search only for a part of a word. The `i` at the end ignores lower- and uppercase.

(Please note that this only searches in the specific field `searchField`)

Comment: @crumb But $text does not allow a regex I'm afraid.